# Sum digits that result from an exponential

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, lua

I am working on an exercise and seemed to be stuck more with how to approach the problem mathematically, rather than syntactically.

The idea is simple when a number is relatively small.  Given a base and power, the program should sum the digits of the result.  Let's use an example to explain what I want to do.

`base 2 and power 8` is given and thus
`2^8 = 256` then the program should sum the digits of the answer so
`2+5+6 = 13` and that is the whole point, to find the sum of the digits of the result of a base raised to a power.

Now, this is in an easy example, if I move to a ridiculously huge number, let's say 2^1000, this is almost impossible to just throw into anything that I have tried as we lose precision because the result is huge and gets truncated.  The answer must be precise.

I thought maybe there is a mathematical way to do this differently, somehow break it up into smaller chuncks but really I can't think of any relationships other than:

`2^1000 = 2^500*2^500`

`1000 log(2) = log(ans)`

Either way, this doesn't get me anywhere near digits in the result that I can start summing.

I hope that I explained it clearly.

For what it is worth, I am using C++ (and gave lua a shot too) and maybe I could use a library but this number would have 302 digit places and I should write my program to handle an exponent of 1000.  I really think I am missing some mathematical trick here.

**EDIT Partial Solution Found**

I have spent a little time with lua trying to solve this today, and I will give it a shot with C++ tonight to see if I get different results.  I can find the source of the error, but I have found a solution that works for most cases.  Just not for 2^1000, and some other exponents with very large numbers.

The solution works described and the Comment from MooseBoys.

I make use of a modular exponentiation.  The lua code is below:

```
-- Function purpose:  Calculate modular exponent (see wiki in comment 
from MooseBoys)
--
-- @param b: base
-- @param e: exponent
-- @param m: modulation
-- @result c: result
-- 
--  example: 2^15    = 32768
--  ModPow(2,15,10)  = 8
--  ModPow(2,15,100) = 68
--
local ModPow = function(b,e,m)
   local c = 1

   for i = 1, e do
       c = c*b%m
   end

   return c
end

-- Function purpose: Check uniqueness of result from last one.
-- ModPow will not return leading 0, so in the case 2^20 = 1048576
-- Sum result would equal 35 because:
-- ModPow(2,20,10^5) = 48576
-- ModPow(2,20,10^6) = 48576  
-- 
-- Also there is an issue with rounding I am working on.  Current Problem
-- Sometimes, result is          6.xxxxxxxxxx2e+294
-- and with leading 0 result is  6.xxxxxxxxxx3e+294  
-- So the result does not catch there was a leading 0 since s1 and s2 
-- are not equal
-- However, this fix is giving me problems (assuming mod exponent always 
-- grows by an order of magnitude.. 10^(n+1) each cycle), I assumed 
-- just checking exponent value is good enough
-- Now I get some strange results as outlined blow    
-- 
-- @param s1: Current result from ModPow (as string)
-- @param s2: Last result of ModPow (as string)
-- @result bool based on whether or not this number is valid to add to the sum 
local CheckUnique = function(s1,s2)  

   if s1:find('e') and s2:find('e') then   --fix rounding?
      if(s1:sub(s1:find('e'),s1:len())==s2:sub(s2:find('e'),s2:len())) then print(0) return false end
   elseif (s1 == s2) then print(0) return false  --fix leading 0
   end

   print(s1) --test
   return true
end


--self explanitory
local base = 2
local exp = 1000
local mod = 10

--Counters and value holders
local sum = 0
local lval = 0
local val,valS = 1,'1'
local cycle = 1


--Know when to stop
local endval = base^exp
print(endval)

while val ~= endval do

   val = ModPow(base,exp,mod^cycle)      
   valS = tostring(val)

   if(CheckUnique(valS,lval)) then         --is unique   
       sum = sum + tonumber(valS:sub(1,1)) --sum leading digit    
   end

   lval = valS
   cycle = cycle+1

end

print(sum)
```

The problem lies within the result.
You can imagine, printing every result from the mod cycle should be something like

```
Value: 1048576
6
76
576
8576
48576
0
1048576
sum: 31
```

I put a print(0) on there when the check detects leading 0, otherwise, prints value of c.  You can see, each first digit will get added to give the correct sum.  Each net line should contain the previous line plus the new digit, like a growing heading basically.

However, the problem I can't solve is now when I extend this to a large number, let's say the solution I cam going for.  2^1000..

Results: (Healthy lines, near the end)

```
2.6725480652012e+288
6.2672548065201e+289
8.6267366100831e+290
1.8626730674387e+291
7.186267401715e+292
0
6.0718626734093e+294
8.6071862673409e+295
0
5.0860718626736e+297
1.5086071862673e+298
7.1508607186267e+299
```

The last line for instance, is the same as if you list the first digits going backwards in the list:
`7.1508607186267e+299`

`7 15086071862`

Being excited, I found the answer to be incorrect.  I looked deeper in to the lines and found these unhealthy lines:

```
9.18229858679e+069
7.5447775000848e+070
8.8906306939456e+069
4.1746958410049e+072
5.0621122825342e+073
4.1602034907325e+074
1.9248790609684e+075 -- no such order 454879 but have 924879?
....
8.3104764719996e+086
3.8310476472e+087
4.6735451839797e+088
8.0281504870817e+089
3.0808317990698e+090
9.0430240225156e+091 --no such order 938438...?
```

There appear to be several areas where this happens, and only on exponents over 200ish.. I checked with 100 and it was perfect.  noticed mistakes in 200 such as

```
2.9937827928353e+018
0
2.0299378279284e+020
2.2029937827928e+021
7.8493010541604e+022
5.0206666406882e+023
0
3.384239167984e+025
```

Anyone have any new tips on what may be the problem?
(sorry, my lua interperter may be different, not sure about lua in general..
I am just using an IDE that is used for game scripts)

Okay, getting closer.  My C++ program handles things a big better and here is the code for it.  Still getting the wrong answer, but at least I am getting the same amount of digits.  I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this now.  The thing is, this exercise is on a website, I don't know the correct answer, just that my program is giving me the wrong answer for 2^1000.  It passes the other test cases I give it (the ones I can do manual and check the answer up to 2^20)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


double ModPow(int,int,long double);

int main() {


    int base = 2;
    int power = 1000;
    long double mod = 10;
    long double val = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    double ans = pow(base,power);
    std::cout << ans << std::endl;





    while(ans != val) {

        val = ModPow(base,power,mod);
        std::cout<< val << "   ";
        sum += int(floor(val/(mod/10)));
        mod = mod * 10;
        i += 1;
        if(i%5 == 0) std::cout << std::endl;

    }

    std::cout << std::endl << sum << std::endl;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;



    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;

}


double ModPow(int b, int e, long double m) {

    double c = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i <= e; i++) {
        c = fmod(c*b,m);
    }


    return c;
}
```

Here, I can see that there is strange behavior during the loop still.  Logically, the exp should increase by one each time as I keep adding a digit.  I see behavior at e+22 and it drops back to e+21, not sure why.  Here is the full result of my program (I have made the doubles long doubles, and added file writing but results are the same as code above)

```
6   76   376   9376   69376   
69376   8.06938e+006   6.80694e+007   6.68069e+008   5.66807e+009   
5.66807e+009   2.05668e+011   7.20567e+012   3.72057e+013   8.37206e+014   
6.83721e+015   8.68372e+016   3.86837e+017   4.38684e+018   2.43868e+019   
6.24387e+020   2.62439e+021   8.81371e+022   7.17853e+021   6.67056e+024   
5.66706e+025   2.56671e+026   6.11305e+027   1.49872e+026   7.84562e+029   
8.79213e+030   5.26226e+031   2.66375e+032   7.26638e+033   4.84075e+034   
3.21959e+035   6.35788e+036   6.73897e+037   6.73897e+037   6.73897e+037   
2.62589e+038   2.98945e+041   2.98945e+041   6.02989e+043   9.17698e+044   
7.16921e+045   7.05229e+046   6.70523e+047   6.5113e+048   4.65113e+049   
8.52121e+050   3.85212e+051   7.38521e+052   4.19563e+053   5.91881e+054   
4.39205e+055   3.9345e+056   9.04097e+057   9.04097e+057   3.68596e+059   
1.49612e+060   7.7534e+061   7.39705e+061   4.22204e+063   6.98596e+063   
6.92886e+065   4.69289e+066   8.22986e+067   1.82299e+068   9.1823e+069   
7.54478e+070   1.14456e+071   4.11446e+072   3.62523e+073   9.90302e+074   
1.92488e+075   4.59175e+076   5.88549e+077   1.35968e+078   6.13597e+079   
6.6136e+080   4.66136e+081   7.48063e+082   6.12132e+083   8.8392e+084   
7.86463e+085   6.94822e+086   6.32933e+087   5.62433e+088   6.56243e+089   
2.3548e+090   5.60251e+090   7.14338e+091   9.90736e+093   6.14551e+094   
5.791e+095   2.5791e+096   5.12015e+097   1.81734e+098   3.08347e+099   
4.30835e+100   4.43083e+101   9.44308e+102   8.62251e+103   4.79117e+104   
4.47912e+105   4.70365e+106   6.26271e+107   9.63625e+108   1.34535e+109   
2.5938e+110   4.77635e+110   7.92388e+112   2.33449e+113   9.38763e+114   
1.74483e+115   4.23631e+116   3.8324e+117   3.10928e+118   8.8341e+119   
9.80234e+120   5.28235e+121   4.52823e+122   8.69571e+123   7.59308e+124   
6.61087e+123   8.34403e+126   8.26135e+127   3.82614e+128   6.83699e+128   
5.48343e+130   7.05731e+131   2.02676e+132   1.20268e+133   3.72264e+134   
4.37226e+135   5.43723e+136   1.68563e+137   9.63719e+138   3.70399e+139   
1.84462e+140   6.61036e+141   4.66104e+142   3.85213e+143   2.38521e+144   
7.39926e+145   4.95209e+146   2.70772e+147   1.27077e+148   9.49987e+149   
6.39539e+150   9.72139e+151   5.89019e+152   7.15679e+153   7.15679e+153   
3.38172e+154   5.84268e+156   9.72579e+157   4.87575e+158   5.6501e+159   
1.85286e+160   4.18529e+161   4.60739e+162   7.12977e+163   5.71298e+164   
8.86201e+165   7.8862e+166   5.82415e+167   4.61194e+168   8.46119e+169   
7.95321e+170   9.01956e+171   7.90196e+172   1.40488e+173   2.38969e+174   
9.12607e+175   8.5208e+176   2.61635e+177   7.26163e+178   1.87538e+179   
6.18754e+180   6.6906e+181   2.05665e+182   3.79061e+183   4.37906e+184   
4.43791e+185   9.87813e+186   1.98781e+187   7.03446e+188   1.57091e+189   
5.7816e+190   7.57816e+191   2.1734e+191   3.5815e+193   9.77689e+194   
8.97769e+195   1.08115e+196   5.10812e+197   4.6079e+198   4.46079e+199   
5.44608e+200   3.69583e+201   3.36958e+202   1.94715e+203   9.19309e+204   
1.7556e+205   9.45675e+206   5.94568e+207   6.45002e+208   9.11561e+209   
1.17058e+210   8.60292e+211   7.86029e+212   2.48236e+213   1.2582e+214   
6.04576e+215   9.60458e+216   4.34447e+217   5.43445e+218   8.42133e+219   
9.84213e+220   1.8562e+221   8.38891e+221   1.08389e+223   7.01599e+223   
1.07016e+225   3.10702e+226   4.3107e+227   1.50548e+228   1.06711e+229   
8.65791e+230   9.86579e+231   8.18076e+232   2.68057e+232   1.85488e+234   
1.85488e+234   2.26339e+236   4.66336e+237   6.27494e+238   5.24964e+239   
3.52496e+240   2.99353e+240   9.96218e+242   8.99622e+243   4.9693e+243   
1.33007e+245   3.78439e+246   1.99925e+247   8.51404e+248   8.47445e+249   
2.95141e+250   7.13201e+251   1.7132e+252   9.76862e+253   9.36726e+254   
3.92421e+255   6.39242e+256   8.42555e+256   4.87969e+258   4.09894e+259   
2.17963e+260   1.61217e+261   8.27277e+261   4.08273e+263   4.53756e+264   
9.67271e+265   9.67271e+265   9.19793e+267   1.91979e+268   2.52109e+267   
5.12996e+270   6.60659e+271   9.64583e+272   6.96458e+273   3.07557e+274   
7.59723e+275   4.30703e+276   6.07449e+277   2.87595e+278   5.82907e+279   
4.59589e+279   2.07609e+281   6.20761e+282   9.17199e+283   5.9172e+284   
5.9172e+284   7.05917e+286   6.70229e+287   2.67023e+288   6.26707e+289   
8.62671e+290   1.86267e+291   7.18627e+292   7.18627e+292   6.07186e+294   
8.60719e+295   8.60719e+295   5.08607e+297   1.50861e+298   7.15086e+299   
7.15086e+299   1.07151e+301
```

Comment: Is this question for exponentiation in general, or just powers of 2?

Comment: Well, this is a mental exercise, there really is no matter to me.  In my mind, a solution that can do all bases should be possible if it works with base 2, but heck, I can't even figure out just base 2.  It was a question posed in mathematics/programming book as an exercise and they just used base 2 in all cases.

Comment: Just a thought, and I haven't really thought about it too much, but I may be wrong. Take 2^n power, the last digit will either be 2, 4, 8, or 6. N % 4 will be 1, 2, 3, and 0 respectively. There are patterns like this for each digit in the entire number. Just use the patterns then add up the resulting numbers.

Comment: Do you sum the digits repeatedly until you get to a single digit, or do you sum just once?  If the former, its trivial -- just compute everything mod 9.  If the latter it is tougher -- you can compute mod 9 and then try to figure out the correction to add to the result to get the right single sum.

Comment: Sum just once.  Okay, I can play around with these ideas.  That is a good idea to mod it down as I go.  So basically just iteratively multiply by 2, mod it, multiply by 2, etc... I didn't think about doing that.

Comment: If it matters to you, Python can do this easily because it supports big integers natively.

Comment: I think I see something spectacular, I see a pattern!

Comment: Hahahah, I feel like that would be cheating. :p  I already used lua to add a bunch of 50 digit numbers :p

Comment: It might be useful to know how you store these numbers, since 2^1000 is too large for even an unsigned long. If you could somehow store it in base 10 you could just addup the multipliers e.g. 256 is 2*10^3 + 5*10^2 + 6*10^1

Comment: [Modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) with a modulus of 10^n is probably the right place to start.

Comment: @MooseBoys Yes, I think this is certainly on the right track.  I can grab the first digit, but then if I mod 100, I get both first and second digit.  By extension, as I increase my mod power, the digits will grow and I have the same problem.  I need someway to shift the digits after I catch the first one.  I am thinking a well placed division can drop the extra digit, but it has to be before, or during looping, not just on the result of the loop.  However, this I think is certainly the right direction, thank you.

Comment: @anoyd_bi_me_grammers There are indeed patterns. The last digit repeats every 4, the last 2 digits repeat every 20, the last 3 digits repeat every 100, etc. The problem is that cycle grows by a factor of 5 per digit... so that could get you the last 2 or 3 digits pretty quick but you'd still have to actually compute 2**1000 to get the top... 298/302 digits.

Comment: @Barry I see that, I posted an answer but deleted it, as it turned out to be very tedious to make a program based on these patterns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a solution that doesn't directly involve just doing `2**1000`? Well, we can do it manually. How many digits does `2**1000` have? Definitely at most 1,000.

Thus:

```
int sum_digits(int e) {
    std::vector<int> digits(e);
    digits[0] = 1;
    int last_digit = 1;

    for (int power = 0; power < e; ++power) {
        int carry = 0;
        for (int idx = 0; idx < last_digit; ++idx) {
            int prod = digits[idx] * 2 + carry;
            if (prod > 9) {
                carry = 1;
                prod -= 10;
            }
            else {
                carry = 0;
            }
            digits[idx] = prod;
        }

        if (carry) {
            digits[last_digit++] = 1;
        }
    }

    // then just sum 'em  
    return std::accumulate(digits.begin(), digits.end(), 0);
}
```

That's pretty quick and obviously correct. Sure the big-Oh time isn't great, but for powers of 1000, 10k, and 100k coliru gives me the answer 0.4ms, 28ms, and 2.8s. Not bad for grade school math?

Comment: man, I've an organic chemist with a PhD... I am math dumb and grade school was a long time ago, and that gap filled with too much.... brain cell death.  I take a look after work and choose the answer.  :D  Thanks.

Comment: tested real quick. For shame, that was some simple math.  Makes so much sense as I went through it.  :D  Thanks Barry.  Enjoy that rep, lol.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ada3d034dd2bf075

Comment: First time making a bounty, thought accepting it gave it to you. Should have it now ;)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned Lua. So I gather you're free to choose a programming language. Then why not simply pick a language that supports big numbers? You say "It completely avoids the point of the exercise, which is to understand the math behind the problem and solve it using an algorithm", but the algorithms you got so far are just "brute force". I don't see too much merit in them.

Whatever, in Ruby it's:

```
(2**1000).to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
```

this gives 1366.

To verify the result I also tried it in giac:

```
s:=convert(2^1000,string)
sum(expr(mid(s,n,1)), n, 0, length(s)-1)
```

(gives 1366 too.)

Turns out I didn't have to: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+digits+2%5E1000) too can solve it.

Comment: Yeah, the other answer suggest the same thing.  Yes, I am able to choose my language, but, the entire point is that I am not just looking to solve the problem but learn something from each lesson in regards to mathematics, algorithms, and programming.

Answer (score -1):

For the exponents up to a 1000 you really don't need to do anything extraordinary. Here's an example in Python, it computes it instantaneously. Building big integers in C++ that support addition and multiplication is very simple, and with just those two commands you can implement power in `O(n log n)` arithmetic operations.

```py
>>> sum(int(x) for x in str(2**10000))
13561
```

Edit: missed the fact that the number itself will have 300 digits. It is still fine for the modern computers, here's an example of computing number of digits in a number that is a result of raising a number consisting of 300 2s into 1000th power:

```py
>>> sum(int(x) for x in str(int("2" * 300)**1000))
1347957
```

Still computes quite quickly

Comment: This does not really answer the question.

Comment: Well, the question, as I understand it, is "how to compute the sum of digits, since I think I can't do it naively", to which my answer is "as a matter of fact, you can do it naively".

Comment: Was not the question, I will not accept this as an answer.  It completely avoids the point of the exercise, which is to understand the math behind the problem and solve it using an algorithm.  

Thanks though.